# jquery autocomplete using mvc3 dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 with EF Code First. I have not worked previously with jQuery. I would like to add autocomplete capability to a dropdownlist that is bound to my model. The dropdownlist stores the ID, and displays the value.

So, how do I wire up the jQuery UI auto complete widget to display the value as the user is typing but store the ID?

I will need multiple auto complete dropdowns in one view too.

I saw this plugin: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ but I am not sure I want to add more "stuff" to my project. Is there a way to do this with jQuery UI?

Comment: I use the jquery ui widget and it works awesome, I fire ajax to return records where they match the term that the user is typing in. It doesn't just 'work' out of the box, you need to add your own ajax call to your data to get the records

Comment: Thanks CD Smith. Do you use it with dropdownlists or just textboxes? It looks like it works well, I am trying to put the parts together so I understand it better. Are there any samples or articles you can recommend?

Comment: I just updated my answer with a link to sample project

Comment: did any of this help answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did FWIW.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#CustomerByName').autocomplete(
    {
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/Cases/FindByName", type: "GET", dataType: "json",
                data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.CustomerName,
                            value: item.CustomerName,
                            id: item.CustomerID
                        }
                    })
                    );
                },

            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#CustomerID').val(ui.item.id);
                },
        minLength: 1
    });

});
```

Works great!

Comment: it will be clear and helpfull for us, if you would post the JSON result controller return method. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

I just posted a sample project showcasing the jQueryUI autocomplete on a textbox at GitHub 
https://github.com/alfalfastrange/jQueryAutocompleteSample

---

I use it with regular MVC TextBox like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MainBranch, new {id = "SearchField", @class = "ui-widget TextField_220" })
```

Here's a clip of my Ajax call

It initially checks its internal cached for the item being searched for, if not found it fires off the Ajax request to my controller action to retrieve matching records

```
$("#SearchField").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var term = request.term;
        if (term in entityCache) {
            response(entityCache[term]);
            return;
        }
        if (entitiesXhr != null) {
            entitiesXhr.abort();
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: actionUrl,
            data: request,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            timeout: 10000,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                entityCache[term] = term;
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.SchoolName, value: item.EntityName, id: item.EntityID, code: item.EntityCode };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (event, result) {
        var id = result.item.id;
        var code = result.item.code;
        getEntityXhr(id, code);
    }
});
```

This isn't all the code but you should be able to see here how the cache is search, and then the Ajax call is made, and then what is done with the response. I have a `select` section so I can do something with the selected value

Comment: @Ryan I'll post up a sample project on GitHub later this morning with a full working solution, it's pretty simple really and reusable when you are going to use it with lots of autocompletes throughout your site

Comment: how does the cache get populated?

Comment: @superartsy Good catch, I forgot that line, was just going from memory. Updated answer, it's in the `success` section of the ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen this issue many times. You can see some of my code that works this out at [cascading dropdown loses select items after post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728206/cascading-dropdown-loses-select-items-after-post)

also this link maybe helpful - http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2011/06/14/cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp.net-mvc-3-using-jquery.aspx